which version of spring-security-crypto jar compatible to support spring version 5.3.27
Hi We are using spring framework 5.3.27 version, Just want to know how to identify the correct jar version of spring-security-crypto can be use in the project.
It is easy way to find the correct dependent jars based on the spring framework version.

There isn't an easy way to do this accurately.
An easy way is to find a popular version that was available at the release date of Spring Framework 5.3.7, ie April 13, 2023. Looking at the maven page for spring-security-crypto it would appear to be 5.7.5 with 441 usages released on Oct 31, 2022.
To do this accurately you can find the Spring Boot version that uses the jar spring-core-5.3.27.jar. This is Spring Boot 2.7.12. This answer should help explain how I got there.
Spring Boot 2.7.12 has a list of dependencies. This indicates that spring-security-crypto 5.7.8 is used. You will also see the dependency for spring-core 5.3.27
